# How do I set up a Test-Kitchen networked cluster

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to set up a cluster of local VMs with test-kitchen so that they can communicate with each other. I don't care if they can talk to the world outside of their little cluster.

Tech in use:

- Test-kitchen on windows 7

  - chef-zero provisioner
  - vagrant driver
  - windows 2012r2 image
- Node 1: Active Directory Domain Controller

  - Provisioned with  windows_ad recipe
- Node 2: SQL 2014
- All others: Windows Dynamics CRM 2015

Situation:

So far I've been able to manipulate the ip addresses that show up in ipconfig on the individual VMs but I've been unable to ping them from either the host box or any other guest machine. I've tried

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[windows_ad::default]
      - recipe[test_active_dir::default]
    attributes:
    driver:
      network:
        - ["public_network", {ip: "10.0.2.10"}]

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[windows_ad::default]
      - recipe[test_active_dir::default]
    attributes:
    driver:
      network:
        - ["private_network", {ip: "10.0.2.10"}]
```

and

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
    cpus: 2
    memory: 2048
  network:
    - ["private_network", { type: dhcp }]
```

The worst part about all of this is about 6 months ago I did something similar and got it to work, but trashed the code when I got the chance to test in a certification environment instead. Cobbling this together last time took me weeks and skimming dozens of blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I spend days in research before finally asking here and minutes later I figure it out on my own.. the answer is to add bridge: to the network thusly

```
suites:
  - name: default
     run_list:
      - recipe[windows_ad::default]
      - recipe[test_active_dir::default]
    attributes:
    driver:
      network:
        - ["private_network", {bridge: 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM', ip: "10.0.2.10"}]
```

the 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM' came from going to VirtualBox ui and looking at the options listed there.

EDIT: I had incorrectly set the network bridge value to 'local area connection 3'. It still worked because it defaulted to the proper value, but I want you all to have the proper information.